# BinaryReader/Writer и UInt32

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, binary

Хочу записать в файл числа 1 и 2 (UInt32) используя BinaryWriter, после чего вывести поочередно все байты в консоль.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"G:\out.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        bw.Write((UInt32) 1);
        bw.Write((UInt32) 2);
        bw.Close();

        fs = new FileStream(@"G:\out.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            byte b = br.ReadByte();
            string byte_in_str = ByteToStr(b);
            Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + ". " + byte_in_str);
        }
        br.Close();

    }

    static string ByteToStr(byte b)
    {
        string bin = "";
        for (int i = 128; i > 0; i /= 2)
            if ((b & i) != 0)
                bin += "1";
            else bin += "0";
        return bin;
    }
```

В результате имею следующий результат: ненулевые биты находятся на 1-м и 5-м месте для каждого из чисел, судя по выводу. По идее число '1' в представлении UInt32 имеет лишь 32-й ненулевой бит, то есть первые 3 байта равны нулю однозначно. А тут ненулевым является первый байт, после чего идут 3 нулевых, что противоречит предыдущему высказыванию. Чего я не понимаю?

[image]

Comment: 32-бит или, точнее 31-ый бит (Most Significant Bit) используется для знака числа

Comment: Так всё-таки как число '1' как записывается в файл? Все 4 бита записываются справа налево? То есть мне понятно, что число имеет вид 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001, но машина записывает его начиная с последнего?

Comment: Похоже, по младшим адресам находятся старшие биты числа.

Comment: Младший - то есть следующий? Если да, то всё понятно

Comment: Число занимает 4 байта и хранится как, условно говоря, по адресу 0 - старший байт, по адресу 1 - следующий байт, и т.д., а по адресу 3 - младший байт.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinaryWriter` использует порядок байт, называемый little endian. Младшие байты записываются в поток первыми.

Comment: Спасибо, так всё понятно.

Comment: @Exide: Тогда поставьте зелёную галочку слева.